# jquery: need help using selector as method

Tags: jquery, methods, css-selectors, tablerow

I am trying to select `<tr>` elements from tables which contain subtables so as to retrieve `<tr>` elements from the tables only and not the subtables, hence why I cannot use the `find()` method. The other challenge is that the tables may or may not have a `<tbody>` hence why I cannot use `children()`.

**The HTML code**

```
<table id='table1' class='toptable'>
    <tbody>
        <tr><td>
            <table class='subtable'>
                <tr></tr>   
            </table>
            </td></tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
<table id='table2' class='toptable'>
        <tr><td>
            <table class='subtable'>
                <tr></tr>   
            </table>
        </td></tr>
</table>
```

**The solution so far**

I found a way to select `<tr>` elements from the tables (whether they have a `tbody` or not) without selecting the `<tr>` elements from the subtables using the child selector `>`.

```
$('#table1 > tbody > tr).length // -> 1
$('#table2 > tbody > tr).length // -> 1
```

**Question**

How can I convert the above selectors to a single method that I would be able to apply to a table object, allowing me to itterate through the `table.toptable` collection and reuse that same method with both tables? (see below)

```
$('.toptable').each(function(){
   $(this).({trs-from-table}).each( ... );
});
```

**JSFIDDLE**

[Here is the link](http://jsfiddle.net/sdalskjdalskjdoij/TCJDp/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should just work:

```
$('.toptable > tbody > tr')....
```

even though you don't add an explicit `<tbody>` the browser *should* automatically insert one for you.

See http://jsfiddle.net/alnitak/reDux/1/

Or if you want to work on a specific table element `$el`:

```
$el.children('tbody').children('tr');
```

e.g.:

```
$('.toptable').each(function() {
    $(this).children('tbody').children('tr')...
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You need:

```
$('tr:has(table)')
```

That will give you a set containing `<tr>` elements that contain a `<table>`.